# Найти наиболее подходящий элемент в двунаправленном списке (СИ)

Tags: c, указатели

Всем привет! Мне нужно найти наиболее подходящий элемент в двунаправленном списке (наименее отличающийся по значению от unsigned int s, передаваемому в качестве параметра).
У меня реализован метод поиска, выдающий первый подходящий элемент.

```
struct node{
unsigned int adres;
unsigned int size;
struct node *next, *prev; 
};
struct list{
size_t size;
struct node *first, *last;
};
struct node* search(struct node *tmp, unsigned int s){
if(tmp){ if(tmp->size>=s){ return tmp; }else{search(tmp->next, s); }}
}
```

Как нужно перебирать список чтобы найти наиболее подходящий элемент? Логично пересмотреть все элементы списка, которые больше или равны требуемому значению и после сравнивать их между собой, находя минимальный элемент, но я не до конца понимаю, как это реализовать.

```
struct node* search(struct node *tmp, unsigned int s){
if(tmp){ if(tmp->size==s){ return tmp; }
else if(tmp->size >= s) {  ?  }
}
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Не вполне: если s больше любого элемента в списке, вообще ни одного кандидата не будет.

Comment: Листать надо внутри search функции, легче, если позволяет задача пересесть на [qsort](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) и [bsearch](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch), работают быстро на не очень крупных данных.

Comment: перепиши поиск с циклом вместо рекурсии... последняя здесь абсолютно ни к чему... думаю всё сразу станет ясно...

Comment: Уточните, что означает *наиболее подходящий*? Больше или равно `s` и максимально близко к нему? Или меньше? Или по абсолютной величине отклонения от `s`?

Comment: Нужно найти элемент максимально близий к s

Comment: Тогда почему вы хотите искать только среди тех элементов, которые больше или равны s?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat У меня стоит задача выделения памяти для элемента, int s - это размер требуемой памяти, поэтому он не может быть меньше.

Comment: Так вам просто на каждой итерации надо считать отклонение (причём со знаком), и запоминать указатель на элемент вместе с минимальным отклонением. Если отклонение 0, то сразу останавливаемся — поиск дальше не имеет значения.